# C++(11) path to URI in Linux

Tags: c++, c++11, path, uri

On Windows there is UrlCreateFromPath(). How do I convert a path to a URI in C++/C++11 under Linux? Of course, it's not just a matter of prepending `file:///`, as various characters have to be %-encoded. I don't want to use an external library for this; I'm looking for something that's part of the C/C++ library, maybe the STL `<regex>`.

Comment: <regex> definitely isn't STL-derived. But the basic problem is that nothing in C or C++ knows _which_ characters have to be %-encoded, or where. (`?` is a good example, that's context-dependent).